# Could Solomon be a married father at the age of 11?

Tags: talmud-gemara, marriage, navi-prophets, king-solomon

While the Bible specifies the age of accession for most of the kings of Israel and Judah, Solomon's age is not given. In his dream at Gibeon Solomon describes himself as a נער קטן  which may be part of the reason [Seder Olam](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Seder_Olam_Rabbah.14.2?vhe=Seder_Olam,_Warsaw_1904&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) says he was twelve years old at accession. Solomon reigned for 40 years and when he died his 41-year-old son Rehoboam became king. Obviously this means Rehoboam was born one year before Solomon's accession. If we accept the Seder Olam figure, this means that Solomon became a father at the age of 11, two years before he had the legal ability to effect a marriage. That a minor cannot effect a marriage is taken as common-knowledge in [the Talmud](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kiddushin.50b.3?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Aramaic&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he): קטן שקידש הכל יודעין שאין  קידושי קטן  כלום.

Comment: A minor male can have a wife through yibbum

Comment: In other words, Seder Olam may be saying that Naamah was Solomon's wife through levirate marriage. It is odd that no-one mentioned this if this was the case.

Comment: It would be odd and I'm not saying that's true, only noting that it is possible to have a wife before bar mitzva, unlike the suggestion in the question.

Comment: Could a 12 year old king take a concubine?

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe a king who is a *katan* can effect *kiddushin* based on the principle that *assur le'hishtamesh besharvito shel melech*, so she is *mimelah nisyachedes* to him, which is the purpose of *kiddushin*.

Comment: Maybe the special gift of wisdom conferred upon him gadol status.

Comment: @ClintEastwood The gift of wisdom came after his accession to the throne and Rehoboam was already one year old when Solomon became king

Comment: @Moshe years don't always have to be full years. If he was king for 40.9 and rechavam was 40.1 years old and it was a short pregnancy, etc.

Comment: @DoubleAA But if the chronology is in order there was at least another three years (ויהי מקץ שלש שנים) before he got his wisdom.

Comment: Was Solomon required to do the mitzvah of giving a bris to Rehoboam if he wasn't bar-matzvah yet?

Comment: The Shu"T (Noda BiYehuda somewhere) discuss the common 18th c. Jewish practice of minor boys marrying minor girls, and whether a) this was permissible (Tos' Yevamos), and b) whether it had any legal force.

Comment: See Gemara Sanhedrin 69B. In the times of King Solomon, men were able to father children at 8-9 years of age and women could give birth even younger. Many famous people spoken of in that Gemara had children at that young age. It may be that the entire concept of Kiddushin was Drabbanan, or a special D'oraisa where the father gives the kesef kiddushin on behalf of his minor son. (Kiddushin 19a is a source from where the possibilities are talked about, although the Gemara there seems to say a minor boy cannot effect marriage.)

Comment: @DavidKenner when you say "the entire concept of Kiddushin was Drabbanan" I assume you mean this only for underage boys & your point is that by Torah law they cannot marry but by rabbinic law they can.

Comment: @MosheWise yes that is what I meant. TY

Comment: perhaps the halachos are different for a king?

Comment: Kesubos 90A the Mishna states clearly that a kattan can get matured through his father. Tosfos Sanhedrin 76B, Yevamos 62B, and 96B explains what exactly the parameters are, but there is marriage (at least nissuin) for a kattan

Comment: @Chatzkel Does **get matured** mean 'get married'?

Comment: @MosheWise yes. That was a typo

Answer (score 2):

The question is based on the Talmud's statement that an underage boy cannot affect a marriage. This is correct, but it neglects the fact that a boy's father can affect a marriage on his behalf ([Mishnah](https://manuscripts.sefaria.org/kaufman_a_50/ms50-100r-large.jpg)). Solomon acceded to the throne in his father's lifetime so David was certainly available to contract his marriage to Naamah when he was too young to marry her on his own.

Answer (score 0):

The Gemorroh in [Sanhedrin 69b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.69b.6?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) brings a machloikes Beis Shammei and Beis Hillel regarding the earliest age one can father a child 8\9 years old with detailed examples from Shlomo Hameleche's mother, grandfather and great grandfather Achitofel. the Geomorroh mentions Beis Hillel opinion ובית הלל סברי לא גמרינן מדורות הראשונים 'we do not learn form earlier generations'. One can understand this to mean that the rules were different then, and in earlier generation  perhaps an 8 or 9 year old could effect a marriage unlike later periods

Comment: The Talmudic discussion there appears to about the biological minimum age for paternity rather than the minimum marriage age for boys.

Comment: The 'earlier generations' that's mentioned there refers to the opinion that the biology in humans changed and that earlier generations had the ability to give birth at earlier ages. This gemara doesn't seem to apply here as it discusses the biology and not the legality of marriage / giving birth.